# Asking for an opinion on By-passing an Op-amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, bypass

Hope you are having a great day, I need to be able to bypass a non- inverting amplifier on my PCB in the future.I am using a header jumper to do this. My question is, should I :
1) short the non inverting input to the output
2) or do the header jumper in parallel to RV4(so that I create a unity gain buffer)

Thanks for the response

[image: My CIRCUIT]

Comment: How "permanent" you want the change to be? In other words, how often are you going to change between bypassing and using the opamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid shorting input and output of the Opamp if you do not plan to desolder it entirely, or to power it off. The additional positive feedback might lead to the amplifier instability (depending on the signal source impedance), and/or possibly damage the opamp.

The better solution is to have the option to turn the opamp to a unity gain stage if you are not trying to bypass it to reduce the system power consumption. To achieve this you have two options:

- Put a header in series with R25 towards the ground. With the header short-circuited you have a gain given by R25 and RV4; without you have a unity gain stage.
- Put a header to bypass RV4 when you want to use the opamp as a unity gain stage.

Answer (score 0):

Here it's a no brainer -- use a jumper to short out your feedback resistor, turning the non inverting op amp into a voltage follower.  As a bonus, you don't need to make your non-inverting input float.

Comment: That is one of my suggestions

Comment: Shorting the output to the noninverting input provides a positive feedback pathway and is thus a bad idea.